# Create single jar from many eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, ant, build-automation

I'm doing the build automation for a java app with ant. This is a client-server app which has many projects in eclipse. I would like to create a jar file for the client and one for the server, but since the class dependencies are all over the projects (in eclipse)... I had the idea to use a tool to automate the search for dependencies. I've been looking at [GenJar](http://genjar.sourceforge.net/) witch is almost all I need but it's not been updated in a while. So I would like to know if there are any other tools like this one, maybe Maven?

Comment: Maven would require you to create multiple jars rather using the same source within two jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also try [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like what you really want is a [WAR file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_WAR_(file_format)).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this is not a web-app

Comment: doesn't necessarily matter.  A WAR is a JAR is a ZIP file; the metadata just let's you describes several places and different kinds of content.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with Ant + [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).  Each project has its own build.xml file and publishes to a central Ivy repository.  Other projects will simply download these dependencies as needed.

The advantage of having an Ant based build process is that you can very easily automate it and use a continuous server to build the entire product after each check-in.